# Dynamic user management in NATS

Tags: nats.io

I think about creating a new solution based on NATS and so far only have two open questions left. In my scenario I need clients to authenticate with the server and of the possible mechanisms user+pass, token and JWT I would like to go for tokens or (least preferred) user+pass.

In the docs I saw that it is possible to [crypt](https://nats.io/documentation/managing_the_server/authentication/) passwords and to store credentials of multiple users. But what I could not find is information about:

- can tokens be stored securely ?
- how can I add new users without reloading the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also store bcrypted [tokens](https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/configuration/securing_nats/auth_intro/tokens)

Also you can also reload the config by running:

nats-server --[signal reload](https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/configuration/securing_nats/auth_intro/username_password)