# How do I hot reload NATS streaming server without stopping the streaming server?

Tags: linux, docker, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I am running the nats streaming server in a docker container and I want to reload the nats specific configuration without stopping the nats streaming server. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, the NATS Streaming server does not support hot reloading. If you want to reload NATS specific settings, you would need to run the two separate (not run the NATS Server as embedded component).

Answer (score 0):

**NATS Streaming Server is being deprecated** - so anyone who encounters this question, note that you should use JetStream instead ([reference from the official NATS docs](https://docs.nats.io/legacy/stan/intro))

Although I'm new to NATS, I've found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59123149/997940) that what you're asking for should be possible in NATS, and therefore also in JetStream - using the following command:

```
nats-server --signal reload
```

The [official docs](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration#configuration-reloading) mention that "A server can reload most configuration changes without requiring a server restart or clients to disconnect by sending the nats-server a signal".

I couldn't find any programmatic way to achieve that, though.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to programmatically reload the nats-server when the config is updated? @Yoav Feuerstein